# Creating Custom Components and Nesting them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am interested in doing something like below in my React Applications i.e. create my Custom Components and nest them in the return statement:

eg:

```
render(){
    return(
        <ShoppingApp>
            <Products>
                <ProductDetail productID={product_id} />
            </Products>
        </ShoppingApp>
    );
}
```

Questions:

1. Is the above possible / feasible using ReactJS ?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, then what will be the practical scenario when this structure can be used / benefits (an example would help in understanding)
3. How to implement this kind of nesting with custom components?

PS: I already know the syntax where we can include a component in JSX inside div, table, . . . , but the question here is how to implement nesting Custom components inside each other in a hierarchy (like described above).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like the special `children` prop that is passed to every component by React (from the docs)

This is specifically applicable when you don't know the what the children to a component will be ahead of time.

In your case, this could be implemented roughly as follows -

```
 class Products extends React.Component {
   render() {
     /* this.props.children here will be an array of all 
      * the children which can be custom components
      * enclosed within the <Products> component 
      * when it is rendered 
      */
     return (
       <div className='products'> 
         {this.props.children}
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

In a real-world scenario, if you want to nest the `ProductDetail` component inside the `Products` component because you want `Products` in some way to pass some prop to each `ProductDetail` it contains, you can use the various well documented utilities provided by [`React.Children`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children) (docs)

So a practical example would be as follows -

```
 class Products extends React.Component {
   getTransformedChildren() {
     return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
       // if child is of type ProductsDetail, clone it so you can 
       // pass your own prop to it else return the child
       const newChild = (child.type === ProductsDetail) ? 
         React.cloneElement(child, { category: this.props.category }) :
         child
       return newChild
   }
   render() {
     return (
       <div className='products'> 
         {this.getTransformedChildren()}
       </div>
     )
   }
 }
```

So your render statement would look like as follows:

```
<Products category='groceries'>
   <ProductDetails id='1' />
   <ProductDetails id='2' />
   <HelloWorld />
</Products>
```

And in this case, all the inner `ProductDetails` children will have a prop `categories` set to `groceries`. However, the inner `HelloWorld` component will not be passed the `categories` prop because it's not of type `ProductDetails`.

Another practical application where this paradigm is used is if you want the parent custom component to passing inline styles to all or some of it's children, and can be very useful if, say, you are writing writing your own libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes above structure is possible. Here you are passing `ProductDetail` as the children of `Products` component, then passing `Products` as the children of `ShoppingApp`.

This kind of scenario is helpful when u have the generic and reusable components. Lets say `ShoppingApp` have 10 `Products` and each `Products` have the `ProductDetails`, in that case u can use the `Products` and `ProductDetail`components 10 times, by using loop you can create the 10 `Products` and `ProductDetail` component. Since all the `Products` will have same properties like Name, Price etc, you can easily write a reusable components and just pass the data inside the components as props.

Like this:

```
_createProductList(){
    let products = this.state.products;
    return products.map((product,i)=>{
        return <Products key={i} data={product}>
                   <ProductDetail data={product}>
                   </ProductDetail>
               </Products>
    })
}

<ShoppingApp>
    {this._createProductList()}
</ShoppingApp>
```

But in scenario Like you can make it more general, since `ProductDetail` is the property of `Product` so instead of using like this u can directly use the `ProductDetail` inside `Product` like this:

```
_createProductList(){
    let products = this.state.products;
    return products.map((product,i)=>{
        return <Products key={i} data={product}/>
    })
}

<ShoppingApp>
    {this._createProductList()}
</ShoppingApp>
```

And inside `Products` Use `ProductDetails` in render. No need to pass it as the children of `Product`.

Hope it will help you to understand :)